# Android going back to previous activity instead of deleting fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have 2 activities with fragments inside of them. Whenever I press the back button, the fragment gets destroyed (Used FragmentTransaction's replace method for adding them into the activity) instead of going back to the first activity immediately. 
How can I achieve the behavior I want to have?

Comment: Don't call 'addToBackStack' method

Comment: post your back button code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override onBackPressed method in your activity and check if the **fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()==0**. If **yes finish()** the activity.

Hope it helps.